# How to find the location of the largest element in an array using recursion?

Tags: java

Given an array list, and the count of element on the list find the location of the largest element using recursion.

So far, I'm able to find the largest element, but I need the location of that element on the array and not the actual  value.

```
private int getLargestElementLoca(int[] list, int count)
{
int largestValue;
if(count == 1){
return 0;
}

int tempMax = getLargestElementLoca(list,count-1);
largestValue = Math.max(list[count-1],tempMax);


return largestValue;
}
```

Comment: It' so idiotic to solve this by recursion, but may train your recursion know how.

Comment: @AlexWien: Not so idiotic you solved this last October :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/19590979/2591612

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding Max value in an array using recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590242/finding-max-value-in-an-array-using-recursion)

Comment: We're going to get silly recursive problems on SO from here to eternity because classroom teachers seem to think there's something cool about using recursion for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you just need some tweaks.  I'm not going to write the code for  you, but here are some clues.

If you want your function to return the index instead of the maximum value, then you need to change the way you compute the return value *and* the way you use it recursively.

```
private int getLargestElementLoca(int[] list, int count)
{
int largestValue;
if(count == 1){
return 0;
}
```

If there is only one element to look at, i.e. `list[0]`, then `list[0]` will be the maximum, and 0 will be its index.  So returning 0 is correct here.

```
int tempMax = getLargestElementLoca(list,count-1);
```

You've redefined `getLargestElementLoca` so that it returns an index, not a maximum value.  That applies to your recursive call also, so `tempMax` is going to be an index and not a value.  That means that you can't pass it directly into `Math.max`.  Some adjustment will be necessary, but keep reading.

```
largestValue = Math.max(list[count-1],tempMax);
```

`Math.max` returns the largest value, but that isn't what you want.  You have two indexes, `count-1` and something else, and you want to compute the *index* of the larger value.  You can't do that with `Math.max`, but you can use an `if` statement or the conditional operator `a ? b : c`.  It would also be helpful to rename the variable, since it's no longer going to contain the largest value.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ajb. I originally was trying to use an if statement instead of the Math.max, but the part that i did not understand is if i  use an if statement how would i indicate what to compare to list[count-1].  If list[count-1] > something[?]{return count-1} else return {?].  I really don’t want you to give me the answer, if you could just explain with clues as you did before.  Thanks

Comment: The reason I changed to Math.max is because i though if i found the largest value, I can then search the array locating that value to get the index. However that did not work.

Comment: @user3282395 The "something" is `list[n]` where `n` is some other index.  That's all I'll say, but you should be able to figure out by rereading my answer what that other index is.

Comment: Thanks again ajb, i re-read your message over and over and was able to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

An idea could be to split your array recursiv into two parts until there are only 2 or 1 elements remainning. Finding the max value in two numbers or one is simple und return it. Then you compare the two returned values and return the max.

Comment: So a binary search, but for the highest number? :)

Comment: You did not read the problem.  He already has code that returns the maximum value (but possibly with a bug).

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is simple, but you should know about doing it iteratively:

```
private int getMaxLocation(int[] array) {
    int maxpos = 0;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
            maxpos = i;
        }
    }
    return maxpos;
}
```

If you were to do this through recursion, you would need to track a few variables across it:

```
private int getMaxLocation(int[] array, int pos, int max, int maxpos) {
    if (pos >= array.length || pos < 0) {
        return maxpos;
    } else {
        int current = array[pos];
        if (current > max) {
            max = current;
            maxpos = pos;
        }
        return getMaxLocation(array, ++pos, max, maxpos);
    }
}

//calling this
int max = getMaxLocation(yourArray, 0, Integer.MIN_VALUE, 0);
```