# Finding a max int value in an array recursive method

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I need help with creating a recursive method that find the max value in a vector. The method should have the following signature:

```
public int max(int[] v)
```

And use a private helping method.

Here's the method that I'm trying to use:

```
private int biggest(int a, int b){
    if(a > b){
        return a;
    }
    else{
        return b;
    }
}

public int maxRecursive(int[] v){
    if(v.length > 1){
        return biggest(v[0], maxRecursive(Arrays.copyOfRange(v, 1, v.length - 1)));
    }
    else{
        return v[0];
    }
}
```

However, all this seem to do is return the middle value of a array.
Ex: If the array is `{1,2,3,5,6,7,8}
the method returns 5.

Comment: you say it has to be found in a Vector, but your code shows you searching through a primitive array. Which is it? Also, why would you do this recursively, that makes no sense. Just do a straight linear run.

Comment: I'm taking a programming class, this is one of the tasks. Managed to create a iterative one but I'm stuck on the recursive method.

Comment: And how are you supposed to deal with zero-sized arrays?

Comment: @PontusBrink that still doesn't explain which data structure you're using. Is it a Vector, or a plain old int array? (please edit the question to not mention the one you're not using)

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590242/finding-max-value-in-an-array-using-recursion (:

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I dont know anymore... I thought int array, because of the header. But since the question is a vector I guess it is that.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It's a vector, and it's an array. It just isn't a `Vector`. An array, mathematically speaking, is a vector; a `Vector` is a specific class in the JDK which also implements the mathematical notion of a vector.

Comment: @Tetramputechture Not allowed to use their header, but I've looked at it :)

Comment: @chiastic-security Thanks for explaining that! Learning more from this than our actual lectures :)

Comment: @chiastic-security but this isn't maths, this is Java, where the word "vector" has a very specific meaning. The mathematical vector does not exist in Java (unlike matlab or mathematica or the like) so any java-context discussion of vectors principally means you're talking about the Vector container. That muddles a question like this. Making sure your terminology matches your audience's expectation is important when asking questions in places like Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error, because you're using `copyOfRange` wrong. It should be:

```
maxRecursive(Arrays.copyOfRange(v, 1, v.length));
```

This is because the `to` argument is **exclusive**. So with your `to` being `v.length - 1`, the array only ends up looking at everything from `1` to the element *before* the last element.

When in doubt, read the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int[],%20int,%20int)).

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off having a method that finds the biggest in the array up to a certain index:

```
public static int findMax(int[] arr, int lastPos) {
    if (lastPos==0)
        return arr[lastPos];
    else
        return biggest(arr[lastPos], findMax(arr, lastPos-1));
}
```

and then the biggest is

```
findMax(arr, arr.length-1);
```

This avoids all the array copying, which is rather expensive. Your code does a lot of copying, which will make it inefficient for large arrays. In this version, you pass the same array around, but as a reference; and you tell the method how far it's allowed to go in considering the array.

The key observation is that the maximum element of an array is either the last element, or the maximum of the array excluding the last element. This is essentially the same as your idea, where you're starting from the beginning; it just makes the termination case a little easier to write and to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the Javadoc for the method you're using (`Arrays.copyOfRange`):

> original - the array from which a range is to be copied
>
> from - the initial index of the range to be copied, inclusive
>
> to - the final index of the range to be copied, **exclusive**. (This index may lie outside the array.)

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the method maxRecursive

```
public int maxRecursive(int[] v){
    if(v.length > 1){
        return biggest(v[0], maxRecursive(Arrays.copyOfRange(v, 1, v.length)));
    }
    else{
        return v[0];
    }
}
```