# How I could find the maxim value of an array with recursive without having an index?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I have that method `valorMaxim([1, 5, 252, 24, 7, 82, 3])` returns 252.
I don't know how to do it. I have been thinking if I could decrease the array length.

```java
public static int valorMaxim(int arr[]){
    int max;

    if(arr.length==1)
        return arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[i+1]) {
            max=arr[i+1];
            return arr[i+1];
        }
    }
    return valorMaxim(arr);

    //Retorna el valor màxim en un array no buit d’enters.
}
```

Comment: Finding the maximum value of an array does not lend itself to recursion, so I guess this is an exercise you have been set, so I won't give you the answer, just give you pointers as to how to approach the problem.  
1/ You will need to pass the `maximumSoFar` as a parameter, as well as the `arrayToCheck`  
2/ The recursive function really only needs to check the first element, then recursivly call itself with parameters, as the max of the first element, and the `maximumSoFar`, and the cdr(all but the first element) of the array). You may find the Arrays class usefull.

Answer (score 2):

I modified the accepted answer to [Finding Max value in an array using recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590242/finding-max-value-in-an-array-using-recursion).

As you suggested (i.e. decrease the array length with each recursive method invocation), I create a copy of the method parameter whose length is one less than the parameter and remove the first element. Then I recursively call the method with the array copy.

```java
public class Main {

    public static int valorMaxim(int arr[]){
        if (arr.length == 1) {
            return arr[0];
        }
        else {
            int[] tmp = new int[arr.length - 1];
            System.arraycopy(arr, 1, tmp, 0, tmp.length);
            return Math.max(arr[0], valorMaxim(tmp));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(valorMaxim(new int[]{1, 5, 252, 24, 7, 82, 3}));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the recursive idea is:

1. If the array has length 1, return the only element;
2. Otherwise, split the array into `x` the first element, and `xs` the rest;
3. Find the maximum element within `xs`, compare it to `x` and yield the greater.

There are two ways to achieve such a "split":

1. Create a new copy of part of the array for `xs`

   You can either use `System.arraycopy` (see answer by @Abra) or `Arrays.copyOfRange`, which is simpler:

   ```java
   int x = arr[0];
   int[] xs = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length);
   ```

   And now we lookup the maximum element within `xs` (which is `valorMaxim(xs)`), and compare it to `x` as the final result:

   ```java
   return Math.max(x, valorMaxim(xs));
   ```

   Put everything together, and don't forget to add a length checker:

   ```java
   public static int valorMaxim(int arr[])
   {
       if (arr.length == 1) return arr[0];

       int x = arr[0];
       int[] xs = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length);

       return Math.max(x, valorMaxim(xs));
   }
   ```

   And that's it! Since we have the length checker in the first place,
   we can safely make sure `xs` would never be empty, and hence `valorMaxim(xs)` would
   never result in `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
2. Set a boundary for the array

   You may have found that copying a new array at each time could be time- and memory-consuming.
   Instead of creating a physical copy for `xs`, we can conceptualise the idea
   and use a bounded array instead. We would need to define a helper method to do so:

   ```java
   private static int findMaxBound(int arr[], int startFrom)
   {
       // does "xs" have length 1?
       if (startFrom == arr.length - 1) return arr[startFrom];

       int x = arr[startFrom];
       int maxInXs = findMaxBound(arr, startFrom + 1);

       return Math.max(x, maxInXs);
   }
   ```

   And then we can define `valorMaxim` as

   ```java
   public static int valorMaxim(int arr[])
   {
       return findMaxBound(arr, 0);
   }
   ```

   In the end, we did not create any new copies of `arr`
   but uses different ranges of itself and treat them as `xs` throughout the process.